# What should I do with the JWT token when a user decides to update his profile info?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

I am making a simple [MERN application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)) and there are users (authorized) that can update their profile info.

I am using JWTs and I create the token with some info about the user, but if he decides to update this info, what should I do? Delete the current token from localStorage and create a new one?

Comment: Storing JWT tokens in localStorage is considered bad practice. If the token is used to authenticate the user, then I think it should not be required to delete the token, since we're still talking about the same user.

Comment: I just saw you're storing user info in the token, which will differ from the new info when the info is updated. I guess replacing the token with the new one (with the new info) will be OK in that case.

Comment: Where is better to storing tokens? When user updated his profile i leave existing token until expire?

Comment: Cookies might be a better option for storing tokens. I don't really know what the consequences are for having 2 active tokens. If you have the option to revoke access of the old token, I would definitely do that!

Answer (score 2):

It might be depend on what you are gonna do with jsonwebtoken. If you are doing just authentication with this then just leave it until expire and get another token from api.

Comment: So, it's mean that there are will be two tokens for the same user? Is it won't be a problem?

Comment: You should replace with new token or refresh token if token expired to keep authenticated. There will be no two tokens for same user at a time.

Comment: User cannot have 2 tokens at a time as when generate new token the old token will be replaced as well.